# If $[F(a):F]=n$ and $p(x)$ is of degree $n$ with $a$ as a root, is it the minimal polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

It is a well-known theorem in introductory field theory that if $K$ is an extension field of $F$ and $p(x)$ is a minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ with degree $n$, then $[F(a): F]=n$. The question I have is if we are given $[F(a): F]=n$, and we found a polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree $n$ where $a$ is a root, is that polynomial automatically the minimal polynomial and hence we can conclude it is irreducible over $F$?

Comment: No. If we found such a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ with $p(a)=0$, then also all multiples $rp(x)$ would be minimal polynomials. The definition of a minimal polynomial also says something about being *monic*.

Comment: This is a technique used for proving irreducibilty of polynomials under suitable circumstances.

Comment: Technically no ... but really yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost true: If $P(X)\in F[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $n = [F(a):F]$ with $P(a) = 0$, then the minimal polynomial $\mu(X)\in F[X]$ of $a$ over $F$ divides $P(X)$ (in $F[X]$). Since always $\deg \mu(X) = [F(a):F] = n$, it follows that $P(X) = r\cdot \mu(X)$, for some $r\in F^\times$. Hence, up to multiplication by a unit of $F$, it is true that $P(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$. In particular, $P(X)$ is irreducible.